# Remove old proxyaddress entry for user in azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have an application which uses Azure B2C and Azure Active Directory.

Problem: User A wants to set his specific email address. But this is not possible because User B already used this email address before. User B has a proxyaddresses entry for this email, although User B does not use the emailadress anymore.

We tried to remove the smtp entry in proxaddresses for User B:

1. Azure Portal --> Values for ProxyAddresses are not editable
2. Windows Powershell

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId <TenantID>
$User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "<ObjectIDUserB>"
$User.ProxyAddresses //Displays all proxyaddresses(smtpEntries)
$User.ProxyAddresses.Remove("<smtpEntry>")
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId "<ObjectIDUserB>" //But then there is no parameter for ProxyAddresses to update
```

Are we missing something here or is there another way to remove a proxyadress entry for a user in azure ad?

Answer (score 5):

ProxyAddresses attribute for a unlicensed cloud-only user is read only unfortunately.  There is a hacky workaround that will remove unwanted proxyAddresses for a cloud only unlicensed user though.  Those steps are:

1. Soft-delete the user with the bad proxyAddress. Example: user@domain.com
2. Create a dummy user dummy@tenant.onmicrosoft.com and update this dummy user's mail attribute with the SAME email that you want to remove from the user soft-deleted in step 1.
3. Using the [MSOnline powershell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSOnline/1.1.183.57) run the following cmds:

   ```
   Connect-MsolService
   Restore-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user@domain.com -AutoReconcileProxyConflicts
   ```
4. Confirm from Azure AD portal that the proxyAddress proxyaddresstoremove@domain.com has now been removed from user@domain.com account. From Azure AD portal, you may now delete dummy@tenant.onmicrosoft.com.

NOTE: This process is ONLY needed for a unlicensed cloud-only user.  If user is a M365 liensed user you can use the M365 admin portal to remove the alias mentioned in another answer.  If the user is a synchronized user from on-prem AD, then on-prem AD is the source of authority and you can update proxyAddress there and sync to AAD.

Comment: I know it's uncouth to do, but I genuinely wanted to thank you for this answer since I don't have any other way to let you know it was a huge, huge help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if AAD Powershell can make it. But there is a quick way to do this.

You can log into [O365 admin center](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/users) with an admin account.

Find the User B and click on it. After the user details open, click on **Manage username and email**.

[image]

Then you can click on "···" -> **Delete alias** to remove the smtp proxaddress.

[image]

Comment: We don't use Office 365 in our AAD. We just use the active directory to signin to our application (Azure B2C). Unfortunately your suggested solution is not working for us. But we appreciate your help.

Comment: I have the same problem and similar/same conditions - I'm using an Azure AD without any O365 subscription/license. A user was mistakenly updated with an e-mail address not belonging to them and although the profile e-mail addresses were corrected, the ProxyAddress entry for that e-mail address has remained and it prevents using that e-mail address for the correct user. What may also be important is that the user is a B2B guest account, not a direct member of the AAD.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple answer, I fought this for hours today.  Simply run a powershell script to add the "smtp" address back to the account that you are showing it was on, then run a powershell to remove it.  We had never AD Synced this account... only thing I can think of is when it was removed a while back from Exchange, it got hung up in Azure.

Add:

```
Set-Mailbox account@domain.com -EmailAddresses @{add="smtpaddress@domain.com"}
```

then Remove:

```
Set-Mailbox Account@domain.com -Emailaddresses @{remove="smtpaddress@domain.com"}
```