Unable to remove old proxyaddress from a user without 365 Mailbox but Synced with AAD Connect
I have some users in my 365 organization that have a SMTP proxyaddress attribute with a Domain I want to delete. Thing is, those users don't have a 365 Exchange Mailbox (and never had..) and editing the proxyaddress attribute in the on-prem AD doesn't sync back to Entra AD.
How am I suppose to remove those SMTP address now ?
I tried editing the proxyaddress attribute on-prem AD but did not remove the Entra ID wrong address.
I tried also removing the unwanted address with Graph but of course I get the error "Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration."

unfortunately not, since we are not using EXO nor have any plans with it...

Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65198916/remove-old-proxyaddress-entry-for-user-in-azure-active-directory?rq=1
